# How to update the content of Meteor.user().profile attributes?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a button that supposed to decrease an attribute inside the user if it is pressed,

I want to decrease the `annualLeave` attribute when its pressed.

```
"profile" : {
        "annualLeave" : 14,
        "replancementLeave" : 0,
        "medicalLeave" : 7
    }
}
```

Here is my code to get the `userID`:

```
Session.set('getUserId', Al.findOne({_id: Session.get('appealId')}));
console.log(Session.get('getUserId').userID);
```

The `appealId` session has the `_Id` of the current item. inside the item the `_Id` of the user, in which the item belongs to is stored in `userID`.

After I get the `userID`, I use it to retrieve the `annualLeave`. Here is the code:

```
Session.set('userDetails', Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get('getUserId').userID}));
console.log(Session.get('userDetails').profile.annualLeave);
```

until now, both `console.log` prints out the values successfully.

Now to final step, I want to decrease the `annualLeave` by 1 and then update the user information in the database,

here is my code (doesn't work):

```
Session.set('counter', Session.get('userDetails').profile.annualLeave - 1);
Meteor.users.findOne({_id : Session.get('getUserId').userID},{$set:{profile.annualLeave: Session.get('counter')}});
```

What am I doing wrong the last part?

Comment: On using the profile: MDG cautions against the profile field due to it being user editable. As it looks like you're managing user leave balances you may want to consider this. See https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the key in quotes if it's not at root level *and* you need to use the `.update()` method instead of `.findOne()`

```
Meteor.users.update(Session.get('getUserId').userID,
  { $set: { "profile.annualLeave": Session.get('counter') }});
```

You can also skip part of your use of `Session` by just decrementing the value:

```
Meteor.users.update(Session.get('getUserId').userID,
  { $inc: { "profile.annualLeave": -1 }});
```

Note that if you're only searching by `_id` you can just pass the value as the first parameter instead of an object.

Comment: Worked! + I used your solution as it is lesser code, thanks